# Замена строк и работа с дефисом

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

С помощью такого кода:

```
var a = "текста, текстов, текст-ами";
a.replace(/текст([а-я-]+)/g,"итог$1 (подитог)");
```

Получается такой ответ:

```
итога (подитог), итогов (подитог), итог-ами (подитог)
```

Как делать так, чтобы получился такой ответ:

```
итога (подитог), итогов (подитог), текст-ами (подитог)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В `replace` вместо строки-замены, можно подставить и функцию. Она будет вызвана для каждого совпадения, и кусок строки заменится на то, что вернет функция.

```js
var str = "текста, текстов, текст-ами";

let example1 = str.replace(/текст([а-я-]+)/g, function(full_match, _1st_group) {
  return (/-/.test(_1st_group) ? full_match : "итог" + _1st_group) + " (подитог)"
});

console.log( example1 );

/***/

let example2 = (full, a) => (/-/.test(a) ? full : "итог" + a) + " (подитог)";
console.log( str.replace(/текст([а-я-]+)/g, example2) );
```